# How to click specific box with same attributes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

[All attributes are same like class, label etc. But need to select specific check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6le4.png)

Comment: Where is html code?

Comment: Provide more info: 1. What are your testing steps? 2. What worked for you? Show code. 3. Where are you stuck?

Comment: screenshot is attached.
1. I create user.
2. create license for that user.
3. Assign license to that specific user. (Here i am stuck to select that specific user).

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("btn-AddApplication")).click();
    
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
    WebElement Chekbox = driver.findElement(By.id("licenseForUser"));
    Chekbox.click();
    
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='button'])[10]")).click();
    
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement search = driver.findElement(By.className("multiselect-search"));
    search.sendKeys(user);
    
    Thread.sleep(5000);

(Now i put code here to select user)

Comment: Please post all info relevant to the question **inside** the question. Please don't screenshot HTML or code or really any other text. Screenshots are for showing UI, etc. All code and HTML should be properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to select users from the search list & don't know how many users will be shown.

provided below code based on attached image

1. Find the  tag element inside by using XPATH or any locator, use 'findElements' because don't know the search list count

`List<WebElement> els = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath of elements"));` --> This will find  tags

2. Iterate the List & select the matched checkbox

   ```
   for (WebElement el : els){
    //el -> points to <label> tage & validating with username
     if(el.getText().equalIgnorecase("your input text")
      {
        //if username matched will check for Checkbox
        WebElement element = el.findElement(By.tagName("input"); 
        element.click() //check box
        break; //if matched user checkbox selected, break the loop
      }
   }
   ```

I hope this is what u need...